# Binding specific ips with Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2, tcpip, centos-7, mongodb-3.6

I am using Mongodb 3.6.3 on Centos 7.

I am running the below command:

`sudo mongod --storageEngine wiredTiger --dbpath /data --bind_ip_all  --logpath /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log --fork`

and everything will work just fine. Except, binding all is not secure enough.

I used to received a logging error when I tried `--bind_ip 127.0.0.1,privateIP` but discovered that the error would disappear when I did `bind_ip [127.0.0.1,privateIP]`.

However, when I tried to connect to mongo locally it would fail and through a my site, it would sit there until it timed out. I checked `sudo netstat -plnt | egrep mongod`and then nothing showed up, which although it successfully forked the mongod process, it did not bind to any of the specified ips.

For reference, when I tried the same command on on the `--bind_ip_all` version it returned `tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:27017           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1645/mongod`.

My question is, why did `--bind_ip ips` fail to bind to the specified ips?

Side Note - when binding ips, should I bind my elastic ip or my private one?

Comment: ,As per your log , able to see you are binding the multiple id. could you share your "mongod. conf" configuration file , for better understanding.

Comment: I have had too many issues with my mongo.conf file, errors out every time I try to run it. The contents of the .conf file are identical to the first line of code in my post.

Comment: What was the specific error message you received when trying to bind to the private IP? What command line did you use to test connectivity when `mongod` appeared to start and you weren't able to connect? In general you want to bind to the most restrictive set of network interfaces required for your use case (typically only localhost and private IP). See the [MongoDB Security Checklist](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/security-checklist/) for a list of recommended security measures.

Comment: `2018-03-26T14:23:35.334+0000 I CONTROL  [main] log file "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log" exists; moved to "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log.2018-03-26T14-23-35".` that is the error that appears if I try to change `--bind_ip local,ipAddress`. It works just fine with `--bind_ip_all`.

Comment: Hrm .. the log line you've quoted is informational (indicating normal log rotation) and unrelated to the `bind_ip` configuration. However, this does suggest successful start up. Perhaps there is more context before or after that line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am running the below command:
>
> sudo mongod --storageEngine wiredTiger --dbpath /data --bind_ip_all 
>   --logpath /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log --fork
>
> and everything will work just fine. Except, binding all is not secure
>   enough.

As per MongoDB BOL [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/) 
 there is **Warning:** Before you bind to other ip addresses, consider enabling access control and other security measures listed in Security Checklist to prevent unauthorized access.

> I used to received a logging error when I tried --bind_ip
>   127.0.0.1,privateIP but discovered that the error would disappear when I did bind_ip [127.0.0.1,privateIP].

As here i would like to say that if you are going to bind multiple ips then as per MongoDB documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net.bindIpAll) To bind to multiple addresses, enter a list of comma-separated values.

**EXAMPLE**

```
localhost,/tmp/mongod.sock

Or 

localhost,192.168.103.100
```

In the above example , let's say i have bind multiple ips. One external ip (192.168.103.100) and another localhost or (in place of localhost, that is 127.0.0.1).

**net.bindIp**

Type : string

Default: localhost

`Starting in MongoDB 3.6, mongos and mongod bind to localhost (127.0.0.1) by default`.

> However, when I tried to connect to mongo locally it would fail and
>   through a my site, it would sit there until it timed out. I checked
>   sudo netstat -plnt | egrep mongodand there nothing showed up, which
>   although it successfully fork the mongod process, it did not bind to
>   any of the specified ips.

The "--fork" is a flag to tell mongod to run as a background process, rather than as an active process which blocks the shell.
The "--fork" is a flag to tell mongod to run as a background process, rather than as an active process which blocks the shell.

Most of time when we shall not configure `mongd.conf` properly ( i mean to say that bindIp, port, and authorization restriction) then get the `timed out error`.

> For reference, when I tried the same command on on the --bind_ip_all
>   version it returned tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:27017
>   0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1645/mongod.

**net.bindIpAll**

Type: boolean

Default: False

```
New in version 3.6.
```

If true, the mongos and mongod instance binds to all ip addresses. When attaching mongos and mongod to a publicly accessible interface, ensure that you have implemented proper authentication and firewall restrictions to protect the integrity of your database.

set the net.bindIp setting to `0.0.0.0,::` to bind to all IP addresses.

As here in the above mongo shell ouput the mongod server returns the pid of localhost with by default port number `27017`.

**Note:** net.bindIp and net.bindIpAll are mutually exclusive. That is, you can specify one or the other, but not both.

> My question is, why did --bind_ip ips fail to bind to the specified
>   ips?
>
> Side Note - when binding ips, should I bind my elastic ip or my
>   private one?

May be your `mongod.conf` configuration file is not configure properly.  That's why you are unable to start mongod server file to that specific ip.

As MongoDB configuration files use the [YAML](http://www.yaml.org/) format.

The sample configuration file of mongod settings , you can find [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/)

For example I am also write down the `mongod.conf` sample configuration file in "YAML" format.

```
storage:
  dbPath: /var/mongodb/db/node1   -- this is the dbPath location 
net:
  bindIp: 192.168.103.100,localhost  -- here there is multiple ip binding
  port: 27011
security:
  authorization: enabled    -- here Authorization is enabled
systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: /var/mongodb/db/node1/mongod.log  -- this is log path 
  logAppend: true
processManagement:
  fork: true    -- here fork is true
```

Untill unless you are not able to run mongod server through your mongod.conf file , That means there is some error in your YAML configuration file.

**Note:** YAML does not support tab characters for indentation: use spaces instead.

Hope this will be help out to you.